# MATLAB rotate xtick labels

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, label, matlab-figure

I cannot figure out how to rotate my xtick labels in a 3d graph. Someone previously suggested:

```
set(get(gca,'xlabel'), 'Rotation',90)
```

But when I do this, nothing changes.

The whole code is:

```
width = 0.7
zheight = 500
set(0,'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder',{'-*',':','o'})

d=bar3(a,x,width)
set(gcf,'color','w');
zlim([0 zheight])

set(gca,'FontSize',14 ,'FontWeight','bold')
set(gca, 'YTick',1:8, 'YTickLabel',{'1','2','4','8','12','16','20','24'})
set(gca, 'XTick',1:7, 'XTickLabel',{'a' 'b' c' 'd' 'e','f','g'})
set(get(gca,'xlabel'),'rotation',90)
```

Comment: I think I want xticlabel, not xlabel, but when I do that, I just get:Error using set
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Error in comp_cost (line 13)
        set(get(gca,'XTickLabel'),'rotation',80)

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103026-how-can-i-rotate-my-x-axis-tick-labels-and-place-an-x-label-on-my-plot

Comment: here is a FEX submission: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate (there are many others)

Comment: @Amro If I use this, what do I Add to my script? Every time I Try calling a function like this I just get errors, probably due to me implementing the function incorrectly

Comment: For instance, if I add xticklabel_rotate(XTick,rot,varargin)
I get:
Undefined function or variable 'XTick'.

Comment: @JacksonHart - There's an example on that FEX page that tells you how to run it. The example is: `xticklabel_rotate([1:5],45,{'label_1','label_2','label_3','label_4','label_5'},'interpreter','none')`.  The first parameter I'm assuming are the locations of each tick.  In this case, each tick goes from 1 up to 5.  You'll need to change this to accommodate where exactly your ticks are located on the x-axis.  The second argument is the angle you want to rotate each label and the third element is a cell array of labels where each cell element is the label you want for each tick.

Comment: @rayryeng When I do this, I get:Unexpected MATLAB operator. and i copied it verbatim, so perhaps there must be something missing.

Comment: Where is the unexpected MATLAB operator happening?  The command prompt will tell you the exact location

Comment: @rayryeng in the line that i added the code you suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this [Rotating X axis Labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels)

Example:

```
rotateXLabels( xlabel, 45 )
```

Comment: I want to rotate the tic labels, the the axis label

Comment: the file will allow you to rotate the tic labels.. then you can rotate the axis label yourself..

Answer (score 12):

As of matlab version R2014b, this is built into matlab. (As noted in the [rotateXLabels package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotatexlabels--ax--angle--varargin--) from the answer by @lakesh)

You can rotate the labels:

```
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 90)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from R2016b you can do:

```
xtickangle(angle)
```